# list.files taking account of file size in R?

Tags: r, file

I have a large number of files in several folders. I can get a list of these files with;

```
MY_FILES <- list.files(WORKING_DIRECTORY, pattern = "MY_PATTERN", recursive = TRUE)
```

Most, *but not all*, of the files are larger than 50Mb. How can I modify the `list.files` call, so that MY_FILES only contains those above the 50Mb threshold? Or do I need another step to subset MY_FILES afterwards? (Not sure how to do this because `list.files` returns a vector of names only, there are no details about the files)

I need to stick to R because this is only one step in a series of data manipulations. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, just get file sizes.

```
x <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)

x[sapply(x, file.size) > 300000]
[1] "./hami.jpg"          "./process_steps.jpg" "./shp_sveta.png"
```

Here I subset only files which are bigger than 300kB. Notice that `atom.jpg` and other smaller files are not included in the subset. You should use `full.names` argument to access files which are not in `getwd()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Roman, a nice easy method. I didn't realise that the `file.size` was still associated with the list. And I really need to work on my understanding of `sapply`

Comment: @EcologyTom `sapply` is easy, it just applies whatever function you specify to each vector/list element.

Comment: @EcologyTom: `file.size` is a function call (in the help index under `file.info`), not an intrinsic property of the file list you get from `list.files()`. The file list is just a `data.frame` of strings/character vectors.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than looping (implicitly or explicitly), a vectorised way to do this is via `file.info`:

```
objs <- file.info(list.files("~", full.names=TRUE))
rownames(objs)[objs$size > 50e6]
```

Comment: Both Roman's and my answer are vectorized. You may want to look up the definition of vectorized for R before opining like that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr lapply is just a fancy loop.

Comment: `.Internal(file.info…` is a `for` loop at the C-level. I guess your code isn't vectorized then either. Using `*apply` or `purrr::map*` == vectorization. Or, perhaps you disagree with the R core folks who wrote the `Vectorize()` function? (could have been S-PLUS folks, too. I'll check the blue book after work).

Comment: @hrbrmstr Using lapply means that the function you're applying, _even if it's natively capable of handling vector inputs_, will be called _once for each element_ in your vector.

Comment: I know that but you're playing games with the term _vectorize_ unnecessarily and in a potentially confusing way for folks new to R just to make your solution sound better (it isn't).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'm not the one who's trying to get all pedantic. And if you think this is an unnecessary distinction: compare `sapply(df, function(x) colSums(data.frame(x)))` with `colSums(data.frame(df))` for a 100000-column data frame.

Comment: You're arguing over C-backed vs non-C-backed vectorization, so you should at least make that distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wrapper for `list.files`:

```
list_files  <- function(path=".", pattern=NULL, min_size=50000000, 
                        all.files=FALSE, full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE,
                        ignore.case=FALSE, include.dirs=FALSE, no..=FALSE) {

  pre <- list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, ignore.case, 
                    include.dirs, no..)

  purrr::discard(pre, ~file.size(.)<min_size)

}
```

Comment: I think it should be `full.names = TRUE`, otherwise I get NAs for file.size and purrr::discard doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread having almost the same question as @EcologyTom. Thanks @Roman Luštrik, @Hong Ooi, & @hrbrmstr for your great solutions!

When replicating each solution, I found @hrbrmstr's solution seems the "most aligned" to the original question and there were quirks with the other two.

@Roman Luštrik's solution generated "./" in front of each file name, e.g., [1] "./file1" [2] "./file2" and so on.
@Hong Ooi's solution included the entire path for each file as part of the output file name.

I found a slight modification to @Hong Ooi's approach that provides output that matches @hrbrmstr's solution--criteria filtered file name output without the extra path information. In my case, not shown here, I saved the output row names to an object for use in additional code to move criteria identified files to another folder directory.

```html
# if desired files are in your working directory, no need to enter path info
# fileSnapshot() outputs a list
# where 5e+7 = 50mb

my_files <- fileSnapshot(path="YourDirectoryLocation")
rownames(my_files$info[1])[which(my_files$info[1] > 50000000)]
```